# TypeLoadException on partial class

Tags: c#, types, runtime, assemblies

I have a partial class `CommandContext` split up in 7 different files in the same folder structure and namespace.

On of the interfaces implemented by this class is `ICommandContext` with following property defined:

```
IUnityContainer Container { get; }
```

When i implement this Interface like this

```
IUnityContainer ICommandContext.Container
    {
        get { return _unityContainer; }
    }
```

I get a TypeLoadException with additional information:

> Signature of the body and declaration in a method implementation do
>   not match.

If i implement the Interface like this

```
public IUnityContainer Container 
    { 
        get { return _unityContainer; } 
    }
```

I get  a TypeLoadException with additional information

> Method 'get_Container' in type 'Data.CommandContext' from assembly
>   'Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not
>   have an implementation.

My code build correctly but at runtime there seems to be an issue loaded the partial class.

Comment: Are you using the Reflection to load a type?

Comment: It also happens when i try to instantiate class directly

Comment: It happens with the reflection because underlying interface definition is different that that of reference definition. It has happened to me many times.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya I have just 1 interface defined with the implementation on 1 partial class. Could u explain what could be wrong. The implementation is matching the interface as i see it.

Comment: In my case I was building one dll library which reference another dll containing the interface (old version). and when run with new version of dll (containing that interface) deployed on IIS it threw the same error mentioned in question. Not sure about your case.

Comment: Strongly quacks like a DLL Hell problem.  The CLR is not loading the same assembly that was used when the program was built.  Probably Data.dll.  Use Fuslogvw.exe and log all binds to get insight.  Watch out for a stale copy in the GAC.  Changing the [AssemblyVersion] number is another way to flush it out.